# Problem with npm resolution resolution from package requiring third dependency

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, node-modules

I have a problem with a requirement, hope you can help me.

I have 1 package named `@unicoderns/orm`, that requires mysql
https://github.com/unicoderns/ORM

Now Im trying to code another OpenSource package named `@unicoderns/cerberus`, cerberus has the orm as dependency, but when I try to build cerberus I get this error:

> node_modules/@unicoderns/orm/connection.d.ts:4:24 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'mysql'. '/home/chriss/Sites/cerberus/node_modules/mysql/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>     Try `npm install @types/mysql` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'mysql';`
>
> 4 import * as mysql from "mysql";

Is obviously trying to find the types of mysql in Ceberus, but they dont exists, why?

Edit 1: typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@unicoderns/orm` lists `@types/mysql` in its `devDependencies`, so `@types/mysql` gets installed when you run `npm install` directly in `@unicoderns/orm`, but not when you run `npm install` in another package that depends on `@unicoderns/orm` (such as `@unicoderns/cerberus`).  If `@unicoderns/orm` is going to have a declaration file such as `connection.d.ts` that references declarations from `@types/mysql` and is intended to be loaded by dependent packages, then [the recommendation](https://github.com/Microsoft/types-publisher/issues/81) is to put `@types/mysql` in the regular `dependencies` of `@unicoderns/orm` to avoid the problem you saw.

Comment: Thanks Matt I was almost sure that was the case but wanted validation, thank you so much again.